# Build an Image from Dockerfile using Pipeline with Openshift/jenkins-client-plugin

Tags: openshift

I am trying to setup an OpenShift Jenkins pipeline to:

1. Get source from git. The source includes a `Dockerfile`
2. Run tests
3. Build an image using the Dockerfile
4. Push the image to an Imagestream

I have created a `BuildConfig` with `Docker` strategy which actually works without the pipeline. The problem is I don't know how to run tests

If I try to kick off the build from the Pipeline it does not trigger the build.

Am I on the right path? What be the best approach for the projects like this? Should I keep relying on OpenShift specific tools? Or move to plain Kubernetes?

I am using a https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin for the pipeline.

Here is my BuildConfig:

```
kind: "BuildConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "front-end-build"
spec:
  runPolicy: "Serial"
  nodeSelector:
    hostname: "vhkdld518"
  source:
    git:
      uri: "https://kraporta@bitbucket/scm/~kraporta/test-kube.git"
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      from:
        kind: "ImageStreamTag"
        name: "nginx:alpine"
      dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
  output:
    to:
      kind: "ImageStreamTag"
      name: "front-end:latest"
```

Here is the pipeline:

```
node {
    stage('build') {
        openshift.withCluster() {
            openshift.withProject() {
              echo "Using project: ${openshift.project()}"
              def builds = openshift.selector("bc", "front-end-build").related('builds')
              builds.describe()
              timeout(5) { 
                builds.untilEach(1) {
                    it.describe()
                    echo "Inside loop: ${it}"
                    return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, it doesn't seem clear what you want to do. You want Jenkins to perform the Docker build? Then I would think that you would want to pull the source into Jenkins and fire off `docker build .`. Then you could authenticate to the OpenShift registry, and do a `docker push`. Alternatively, what you seem to be doing is defining the build to have OpenShift perform the build, but using Jenkins to trigger it. And I don't see anything in your Jenkins pipeline that actually *triggers* the build, only lists them. You could skip Jenkins altogether, and use a git webhook to trigger OpenShift's build.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but i'd to keep it as reference.

**the issue:**
there's missing step, you haven't start the build process so there's no builds!

**the solution:**
we need to start the build process before fetching the builds, here:

```
def builds = openshift.selector("bc", "front-end-build").related('builds')
```

to be (there's many way to be done):

```
def buildConfig = openshift.selector("bc", "front-end-build")
openshift.startBuild("front-end-build") # we started the build process
def builds = buildConfig.related('builds')
```

check: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin#watching-and-waiting-of-course